Emulating NFC Cards in Kotlin Android with HCE
I am trying to emulate an NFC card on my Android application, but the NFC reader that I'm using (another phone with NFC Tools app) doesn't read anything. And my Apdu service doesn't receive any command.
I added this in my Manifest:
        <service
            android:name=".MyHostApduService"
            android:exported="true"
            android:permission="android.permission.BIND_NFC_SERVICE">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.nfc.cardemulation.action.HOST_APDU_SERVICE" />
            </intent-filter>

            <meta-data
                android:name="android.nfc.cardemulation.host_apdu_service"
                android:resource="@xml/hce_service" />
        </service>

I created MyHostApduService:
class MyHostApduService : HostApduService() {

    companion object {
        val TAG = "Host Card Emulator"
        val STATUS_SUCCESS = "9000"
        val STATUS_FAILED = "6F00"
        val CLA_NOT_SUPPORTED = "6E00"
        val INS_NOT_SUPPORTED = "6D00"
        val AID = "A0000002471001"
        val SELECT_INS = "A4"
        val DEFAULT_CLA = "00"
        val MIN_APDU_LENGTH = 12
    }

    override fun processCommandApdu(commandApdu: ByteArray, extras: Bundle?): ByteArray? {
        Log.i(TAG, "APDU Command Received: ${commandApdu.joinToString()}")

        val hexCommandApdu = toHex(commandApdu)
        if (hexCommandApdu.length < MIN_APDU_LENGTH) {
            return hexStringToByteArray(STATUS_FAILED)
        }

        if (hexCommandApdu.substring(0, 2) != DEFAULT_CLA) {
            return hexStringToByteArray(CLA_NOT_SUPPORTED)
        }

        if (hexCommandApdu.substring(2, 4) != SELECT_INS) {
            return hexStringToByteArray(INS_NOT_SUPPORTED)
        }

        if (hexCommandApdu.substring(10, 24) == AID)  {
            return hexStringToByteArray(STATUS_SUCCESS)
        } else {
            return hexStringToByteArray(STATUS_FAILED)
        }
    }

    override fun onDeactivated(reason: Int) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Deactivated: $reason")
    }

    private val HEX_CHARS = "0123456789ABCDEF"
    private fun hexStringToByteArray(data: String) : ByteArray {

        val result = ByteArray(data.length / 2)

        for (i in data.indices step 2) {
            val firstIndex = HEX_CHARS.indexOf(data[i]);
            val secondIndex = HEX_CHARS.indexOf(data[i + 1]);

            val octet = firstIndex.shl(4).or(secondIndex)
            result.set(i.shr(1), octet.toByte())
        }

        return result
    }

    private val HEX_CHARS_ARRAY = "0123456789ABCDEF".toCharArray()
    private fun toHex(byteArray: ByteArray) : String {
        val result = StringBuffer()

        byteArray.forEach {
            val octet = it.toInt()
            val firstIndex = (octet and 0xF0).ushr(4)
            val secondIndex = octet and 0x0F
            result.append(HEX_CHARS_ARRAY[firstIndex])
            result.append(HEX_CHARS_ARRAY[secondIndex])
        }

        return result.toString()
    }
}


And created the xml file:
<host-apdu-service xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:description="@string/service_name"
    android:requireDeviceUnlock="false">
    <aid-group android:description="@string/service_name"
        android:category="other">
        <aid-filter android:name="F0010203040506"/>
        <aid-filter android:name="F0394148148100"/>
    </aid-group>
</host-apdu-service>

The Android device where I'm testing my application is a Galaxy A31 with Android 12.
But it doesn't work, the processCommandApdu doesn't log anything. Do I need to add anything else? Or could it be reader's fault?

I don't see any code to start the HCE service, may be you could check your devices with known working code like the HCE example at https://github.com/underwindfall/NFCAndroid/tree/master

The NFC Tools app is trying to read a lot of NFC tags, but for this the app tries some commands to connect to the NFC tag. One of the first commands is the "Select Data File" command that asks for a dedicated "file name" that is equals to the AID of the tag. As your emulated tag runs with proprietary AIDs (e.g. "F0010203040506") the NFC tools app will not "call" the Kotlin app and your processApdu method will never get called.

You will have 2 choices: run an NFC Reader app that calls for your AID in the "hce_service.xml" file or (for starting) use a well know AID that is used when transmitting NDEF messages - this would be "D2 76 00 00 85 01 01".

It's possible to emulate a card with always the same UID?
